# how react-redux gets the store object of provider?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Here is a basic react-redux app ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/my-redux-question-on-stack-847ll)):

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { useDispatch, Provider, useSelector, useStore } from "react-redux";
const App = () => {
  const store = useStore(); // <- how it gets the store object of Provider ?
  const state = useSelector(s => s);
  return <div>{state}</div>;
};
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStore((state, action) => 5)}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Now my question is:

How hooks like `useStore` gets the store object we set in `<Provider store={store}>` ?

If it was dom, we could use `this.closest('.provider').getAttribute('store')` to get the store attribute of the provider element in parents. But how we can do it in react?

I'm asking it because i want to understand how react-redux works behind the scenes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`react-redux` uses a provider that holds all of the properties it works with. It allows you to pull the internals from the provider through nice APIs such as the hooks API (`useStore`, `useDispatch`), or through the `connect()` HOC API.

To help you visualise it in a simpler way, let's write a "mini" react-redux using React Context API

```
import React, { createContext, useContext } from 'react';

const InternalProvider = createContext();

/**
 * This is the `Provider` you import from `react-redux`.
 * It holds all of the things child components will need
 */
const Provider = ({ store, children }) => {
  /**
   * This `context` object is what's going to be passed down 
   * through React Context API. You can use `<Consumer>` or 
   * `useContext` to get this object from any react-redux-internal
   * child component.  We'll consume it on our `useStore` and
   * `useDispatch` hooks
   */
  const context = {
    getStore: () => store,
    getDispatch: (action) => store.dispatch,
  };

  return (
    <InternalProvider value={context}>
      {children}
    </InternalProvider>
  );
}


/**
 * These are the hooks you import from `react-redux`.
 * It's dead simple, you use `useContext` to pull the `context`
 * object, and voila! you have a reference.
 */
const useStore = () => {
  const context = useContext(InternalProvider)
  const store = context.getStore();
  return context;
};

const useDispatch = () => {
  const { getDispatch } useContext(InternalProvider);

  return getDispatch();
};


/***************************************
 * Your redux-aware components
 *
 * This is how you consume `react-redux` in your app
 */
const MyComponent = () => {
  const store = useStore();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return <>Foo</>
}

const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <MyComponent />
  </Provider>
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. you have a small syntax error: it should be:  `InternalProvider.Provider` . I implemented a basic one and it worked: https://codesandbox.io/s/my-stack-q-answer-hs01q So in short it uses `react context`, and `react context` lets us access the value on a specif parent (with `createContext` and `useContext`). It's so nice. Thanks for your time.